# Get the error WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed because the class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer can not be found

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, servlet-container

I hope someone can help me with my problem.

Currently I'm trying to deploy a Java EE project on a Wildfly 16 server. However, deployment aborts with the following error message:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."webservice-impl-1-3.0.0.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."webservice-impl-1-3.0.0.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "webservice-impl-1-3.0.0.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server@8.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer from [Module "deployment.webservice-impl-1-3.0.0.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs@16.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs@16.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scanWebDeployment(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:278)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs@16.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:109)
    at org.jboss.as.server@8.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer from [Module "deployment.webservice-impl-1-3.0.0.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs@16.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:435)
    ... 11 more
```

As far as I know I have no corresponding dependency. Or do I have to choose another jaxb implementation if I want to deploy my webservice on a wildfly?

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0.1</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
                <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.26</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.26</version>
            </dependency>
```

Do I have to change anything in the default configuration (domain.xml, ...)?
Or what else could be of interest to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found my stupid mistake. Since I'm moving the project from Glassfish to Wildfly, I also have to change the web.xml ...